# Is it possible to set Android app permissions globally or in batches?

Tags: permissions

On android 10, is it possible to select multiple apps and to set their access or security permissions all in one go, rather than having to select each app individually?

For context, I have a device with many rarely used apps, and Google keeps removing their permissions automatically.

The setting for telling android not to do this seems to be per app, not per device. The device is old and slow so going to each app individually is a chore.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate, depending on the requirement: [How can I disable the Android 11's auto-reset permissions globally?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/244606/44325)

Comment: That only applies to Android 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each app, you have to change the permission in App settings, or you can change it overall based on the brands.

For that, follow https://support.google.com/android/answer/9431959?hl=en#zippy=%2Cautomatically-remove-permissions-for-unused-apps

[image]

Comment: I find it hard to believe that there is no central way to enable or disable this feature, having to do it for every app seems counter productive. Especially in corporate\managed environments where there might be thousands of apps on hundreds of devices. Surely a school IT tech wouldn't be expected to do this individually for every app on every tablet that the school owned?